# Call Onclick of Div Using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to alert something in the onclick event of a div .

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('new_div').click(function() {
    alert(1);

});

</script>

<div id="new_div" style="border:1px solid;">
Clicked Me......
</div>
```

But when loading the page it displays an error:

```
document.getElementById("new_div") is null
```

What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you defined that div after your javascript code, so when you add your handler the div doesn't exist yet

reverse your code like so

```
<div id="new_div" style="border:1px solid;">
Clicked Me......
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
   console.log(document.getElementById('new_div'))
</script>
```

to correctly attach an event use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/DOM/element.addEventListener) (and [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE<9)
or simply use `document.getElementById('new_div').onclick = ...` (but not recommended since you remove any previous defined handler, if any)

Comment: you should define your handler via addEventListener/attachEvent. maybe you want simply do `document.getElementById('new_div').onclick = ...` but it's not recommended

Comment: You are trying to assign events by jQuery syntax.

Comment: F.Calderan: Why wouldn't you assign an event by .onclick = handler?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: This should be a better solution, I'm a bit rusty in JavaScript.

You need to load your JavaScript event handlers after the page is loaded. The simplest way is making your code load when the document finishes loading and the window casts an onload-event.

```
<script type="JavaScript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('new_div').onclick = function() {
        alert("Good morning, you are very beautiful today!");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Even though that's not the best way, this is definitely the best answer.

Comment: I'm bit rusty in JS, do you think my current solution is better?

Comment: Yep, way better :-) The other way would be to have the `script` tag after the `div`, so that you don't even need `window.onload`.

Answer (score 0):

The new_div is not yet loaded when your javascript executes.

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#new_div').click(function()
    {
        alert(1);
    }); 
});
```

**Edit**

I assume you use jQuery because you use `.click(function() {`

Comment: i only needed in javascript not in jquery

Comment: The problem is you're using jQuery while you're not using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   function clicked(item) {
    alert($(item).attr("id"));
   }
  </script>


  <div onclick="clicked(this);" id="test">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you jquery solves your problem beautifully.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#new_div').click(function() {
    alert(1);
    });
});
</script>
```

your HTML stays the same

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
          <html>
       <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#new_div").click(function(){
        alert(1);
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>

   <body>
    <div id="new_div" style="border:1px solid;">
    Clicked Me......
       </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```